# pipenv : The term 'pipenv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: python, virtualenv, pipenv

I installed `pipenv` using `pip install pipenv`, there're no issues.

```
PS D:\GitHub\newhome.ca> pip install pipenv
Requirement already satisfied: pipenv in c:\users\hustler\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (2020.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in c:\users\hustler\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from pipenv) (20.0.27)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in c:\users\hustler\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from pipenv) (2020.6.20)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv-clone>=0.2.5 in c:\users\hustler\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from pipenv) (0.5.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pip>=18.0 in c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages (from pipenv) (18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=36.2.1 in c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages (from pipenv) (40.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata<2,>=0.12; python_version < "3.8" in c:\users\hustler\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (1.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six<2,>=1.9.0 in c:\users\hustler\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: distlib<1,>=0.3.1 in c:\users\hustler\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (0.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs<2,>=1.4.3 in c:\users\hustler\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.0.0 in c:\users\hustler\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (3.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in c:\users\hustler\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from importlib-metadata<2,>=0.12; python_version < "3.8"->virtualenv->pipenv) (3.1.0)
You are using pip version 18.1, however version 20.2b1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

as you can see above, but when I run `pipenv --version` I get this error:

```
PS D:\GitHub\newhome.ca> pipenv --version

pipenv : The term 'pipenv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pipenv --version
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pipenv:String) [], CommandNotFoundExcepti
   on
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I also added the path of `pipenv`,namely `c:\users\hustler\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages\pipenv` in path of environment variables, but still getting this error.

Comment: You don't need the path of pipenv, only ..\PythonXX\Scripts\

Comment: I thought it may help, because previously there were a message stating you should add it in your path, so I did it. I uninstalled then reinstalled. nothing works fine

Comment: It is already installed, did you check `pipenv --version` after fixing the scripts path?

Comment: it is already installed, but I did everything it is not working

Comment: is the path correct then? Go to Scripts location and see if you find the file `pipenv.py`, if it is there then copy the exact path and add it to environment path variables, remember to delete the old one, or you can just edit the old one, in path you should have one for Python and the other for Scripts, it should look like this `c:\users\hustler\appdata\roaming\python\python37\Scripts\\`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `python -m pipenv shell` ?

Answer (score 1):

One common solution to errors similar to this one is to add the path to your scripts folder to your path and restart your session of powershell.

The path should look something like this: `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts`

Comment: It may be overkill but have you attempted restarting your entire computer?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the script folder and the site-packages folder on the system variable path.

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages

C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts
```

that worked for me